# How can I create CSS variables with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables, cssom

I'm using `:root` to create some CSS variables. Is it possible to create them with JavaScript instead of CSS? Below is a simple example:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

```
:root {
  --first-color: #000;
  --second-color: #666666;
}

#container {
  background-color: var(--second-color);
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via [.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method:

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty('--first-color', 'red');
root.style.setProperty('--second-color', 'blue');
```

```css
p {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

div {
  color: var(--second-color);
}
```

```html
<p>First color</p>
<div>Second color</div>
```

Comment: Bless you. This was just the approach I needed for a problem I was having in Svelte.